Does midnight (00:00) mean the time at the end of day depending on the locale for cron?
Here in France, midnight 00:00 is the end of the day, in English it is the beginning of the day.
In a cron table, if a batch is scheduled at 00:00 Friday, it will  finish in the morning of Friday.
My question is: Does changing the locale and time locale change the definition of midnight?
If I configure a server with the french locale, will the batch scheduled at 00:00 Friday finish Saturday morning?

Be aware that days do not always start at the time 00:00. On same dates in some time zones, the day may start at another time such as 01:00.

@BasilBourque And when using some calendars as well. There are at least a few cultures that consider a day to be sunset to sunset or sunrise to sunrise.

so a day in France starts at 00:01 and ends at 00:00?

In UTC, by definition, 23:59:59 is the last second of the day (unless there's a leap second added, which will be 23:59:60), and 00:00:00 is the first second of the next day. The locale has no influence in this.

@tvde1 yes in france in you give a meeting at thursday midnight the french will come at 23H45 the thursday to be slightly ahead.

@BasilBourque i'am interested, do you have some example please ?

@Bussiere Jordan. And Palestine, Bangladesh, Iran, Japan, and more. Open the tzdata, search for 24:00.

I know common usage of « minuit » in French is midnight at the end of the day, but even with a French locale, 0:00 indicates midnight at the start of the day:
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 date -d ""
mar. 26 nov. 2024 00:00:00 CET

A cron job scheduled for 0:00 on a Friday, running for less than twelve hours, will finish on the Friday morning.

Can one use 24:00 to mean the end of the day?

@A.Rex I would use 23:59 for the end of the day (yes, it is one minute short of the end, but it is also unambiguous). I would also use 0:01 for start. In general, using 0:00 can be confusing and is not well defined, as you have just found. "Technically" there is no such time as 24:00, but it is occasionally used to disambiguate. This is in communication between people, though, and may not apply to computers.

@A.Rex no, at least not with cron — crontab allows the hour field to take values between 0 and 23 included.

@enkorvaks "00:00" is well defined.  It's the start of the first minute of a day. This follows from the fact that the hours field has values in the range 0-23 and the minutes field has values in the range 0-59.

@Kusalananda: In the Gregorian Calendar, yes. In the Hebrew and Muslim Calendar, no. (They set "start of the day" at sunset.) Locales are a tricky business.

@DevSolar I'm not talking about calendars. I'm talking about what range of numbers are valid in the time fields of a crontab schedule. If "of the day" is a potentially confusing concept, maybe I should have said "after midnight"?

When you look at insurance coverage, that often ends at 23:59 or starts at 00:01 to avoid the problem (but your actual coverage still ends or starts at midnight). And “noon” is often used to avoid the same problem with 12am or 12pm.
